# What can cause a file to self destruct itself?

Tags: huawei, files

I had a file on my device (Huawei Mate SE, Android version 8) which I downloaded few months ago.

Few days ago, the file disappeared. It's just gone and I can't find any trace of it. I'm 100% sure I did not delete it myself.

No other file is gone, only that one. This is the first time such thing happens to me, on any device.

If it matters, the file is a song (audio only mp4).

What can cause such a thing?

Additional info about the file:

- It was downloaded via a browser on a desktop computer, sent to myself via email and downloaded on the phone from that email. I deleted the original file on the computer.
- I don't know if the file had any special protection.
- I have several other files downloaded in this exact way, all of them are fine.

Comment: What steps does your music player  need to delete a song/audio file? Files don't disappear on their own so something must have triggered deletion. Also, how are you trying to access that file? Using music player or using file manager app?

Comment: @Firelord to delete a song via the player I need to tap a three vertical dots icon, choose "Delete" in a menu and confirm. I'm 100% sure I never did that with the song that disappeared. I access it only via the music player, while playing the whole playlist, or choosing to play it directly. I never used the file manager to access a song. I know it's weird, that's why I was hoping someone might know something about it... :)